# How can I explicitly get product image URLs which use the insecure media URL as their base?

Tags: url, helper, product-images, gallery

Our default site configuration uses a CDN for our insecure media URLs and no CDN for our secure media URLs.  This is how things should work the majority of the time, but we have a case that needs to explicitly retrieve insecure URLs despite normally being a secure request.

The code which returns the URLs is using the product and the image helper to return resized versions of the media gallery:

```
foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
    $imageUrl = (string) Mage::helper('catalog/image')
                ->init($product, 'image', $image->getData('file'))
                ->keepFrame(false)
                ->constrainOnly(true)
                ->resize($imageSize);

    $imageUrls[] = $imageUrl;
}
```

What's the best way to return resized insecure product gallery image urls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of *stuff* going on to give you those urls. If you really want to swap it to insecure, the easiest way is probably to run `str_replace(Mage::getBaseUrl('media', true),  Mage::getBaseUrl('media', false), $imageUrl, 1)`

Comment: That's what I've put in place temporarily. Any idea if there would be a configurable way to set a given route/handler to always behave as secure/insecure?

Comment: Don't think so, you're calling Catalog/Image->toString to get the url, you could probably extend the class to add a `secure` parameter to pass down to the getUrl calls.